# Is there a way to view the page layout in the output of a document?

Tags: geometry, layout

I'm wrestling with `geometry` right now, trying to increase the width of the body, without success. It would be very useful to be able to see the page layout (lines/boxes indicating edges of the body, margins, headers, footers, etc.) so I can visualise the effect (if any) the adjustments I'm making are having on the page.

Is there an easy way to see these lines?

Comment: See `layout` package

Comment: Have you tried [the option `showframe`](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf#page=12)? `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showframe` option in the geometry package (as marquinho points out) can show the appropriate layout lines. It can be found documented in [the package's manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/geometry.pdf/0) in section 5.7 (Other options).

Answer (score 0):

The `layouts` package (`texdoc layouts` to see the manual).

It enables the display of the position of text on the page, the disposition of floats, the layout of lists and footnotes, the design of section headers, and other aspects. You can also experiment with potential layout designs.

Comment: Does this draw the layout on a pre-existing document? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @EnronEvolved It can draw the layout of the current document and draw proposed layouts as explained in the manual and specified in the answer. You could have looked at the manual to see what it is capable of. --- GOM

Comment: I did and couldn't see any examples of it doing so.

Comment: Figure 3 in the manual shows the page layout of the current document and Figure 5 shows an experimental layout. Are you sure you looked at the manual (`texdoc layouts`)? There is different package named `layout`(`texdoc layout`). Are you sure that you didn't look at that one?

Comment: @EnronEvolved Have you at last read the `layouts` manual? If not, why not?